array of pointers to pointers to integers VS pointer to pointer to array of integers
I have 3 integers A, B & C from which I make pointers that I group in an array arrayABC of pointers to pointers:
int A = 1;
int B = 2;
int C = 3;

int *ptA = &A;
int *ptB = &B;
int *ptC = &C;

int **arrayABC[] = { &ptA, &ptB, &ptC };

Meanwhile I have the array of integers DEF:
int DEF[] = {4,5,6};

I would like to wrap it in an array arrayDEF of pointers to pointers offering the same interface as the array arrayABC. I tried the following:
int **arrayDEF[] = &(int *){&DEF};

My final goal is to be able to group arrayABC and arrayDEF in a parent array arrayGlobal like that:
int ***arrayGlobal[] = {arrayABC,arrayDEF};

I need to be able to access arrayGlobal like that:
printf("A = %d\n", **arrayGlobal[0][0]); // A = 1
printf("B = %d\n", **arrayGlobal[0][1]); // B = 2
printf("C = %d\n", **arrayGlobal[0][2]); // C = 3
printf("D = %d\n", **arrayGlobal[1][0]); // D = 4
printf("E = %d\n", **arrayGlobal[1][1]); // E = 5
printf("F = %d\n", **arrayGlobal[1][2]); // F = 6

I'm able to compile without any error. However, the execution leads to a segmentation fault. I suspect that the type of arrayDEF (pointer to pointer to array of integers) is similar to the one of arrayABC (array of pointers to pointers to integers) but not equivalent. Do you confirm ?
Edit: Some more context
I'm developing a program which will be integrated in a much larger one. I'm provided with an interface file containing a huge list of pointers. I can't change this list and I have no guarantee that the address pointed by the pointers won't change during the execution. I must then absolutely work with the pointers.
As I need to iterate on all these pointers I grouped them in an array.
I need also to have a parallel table to store results. The best structure for my need is the one like arrayGlobal in my example. By doing this, I can use the first index to switch between the interface table (0) and the result table (1). The second index allows me to iterate on the pointers.
I could easily form my result table using the same structure as the array arrayABC by doing something like that:
int *ptD = &DEF[0];
int *ptE = &DEF[1];
int *ptF = &DEF[2];
int **arrayDEF[] = { &ptD, &ptE, &ptF };

This will work for sure, however, if this is pretty ok for an example with 3 pointers, it will be very heavy with hundreds of pointers. The initialization of **arrayABC[] is already very heavy (but imposed by the interface), I wanted to avoid doing the same for my result table and tried to look for a more one line instruction.
I believed erroneously that a pointer to pointer to array of integers could be equivalent to an array of pointers to pointers to integers as an array is always referenced with its first element. So, defining an array containing the pointers to all elements of an array like this:
int array={1,2,3};
*ptarray[] = {&array[0], &array[1], & array[2]};

Could also be achieved like that:
*ptarray[] = (int *[]){&array};

The compiler (gcc) compiles (with warnings) but at the execution, it works to access the first element of the pointed array, however creates a segmentation fault for the next ones.

A side note: see: Three Star Programmer.

The type of &DEF is int (*)[3]. By casting it to int * you lie to the compiler. And while arrayABC is an array of pointers to pointers to int variables, arrayDEF is something completely different.

Please [edit] your question and explain what problem you want to solve. Why do you need to store the addresses of pointers. Why do you need to be able to access arrayGlobal using ***?
Storing &ptA is only necessary if you want to modify the value of ptA based on this array, which would make ptA point to somewhere else than A.

An array is not a pointer, and any use of casts cannot change that fact.

I think that may work : extracting addresses of all elements from arrayABC and other arrays and appending in the int *arrayGlobal[] with memcpy or a loop. You can also look this answer

@Bodo Yes, you pointed it out: as I said, the ptA and following pointers are provided to me in an interface file and I must comply with that. I have no guarantee that addresses to which they point won't change, so I must keep on working with the pointers. As I need to iterate on all these values I stored the pointers in an array, which eases the handling.
As I need a parallel array to store some results, I could easily reproduce the same structure but I would have to declare again so many pointers. I hoped I could find a nicer one line solution with an int array (DEF in my example)

@Emre Thanks for the idea, however it doesn't solve the problem : as per specification and interface constraints, I can't change the structure of arrayABC and thus require arrayGlobal to be int ***. The only thing I can change is arrayDEF in order to adapt DEF to ***arrayGlobal[1]

Good job on addressing comments, however, you want to revise the question with clarifications or additional data and not respond with a comment.  Make it even more concrete, I need to call function foo(int **arrayDEF[]) (aka int ***) and I have this data how do build a suitable type to call foo().  The tell the story twice and it mostly just muddies the water.

Two different data structures are different. You cannot bend them to the same shape.

5 star programming!!
